# Error while creating snapshot in fs in elasticsearch 7.3.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to create snapshot in elasticsearch i have defined the path.repo in elasticsearch.yml correctly pointing the folder elasticsearch_backup and it is having permissions

```
path.repo: /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch      4096 Dec 12 06:55 elasticsearch-backup/
```

I am using this api from kibana -

```
PUT /_snapshot/elasticsearch-backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "compress": true,
    "location": "/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup"
  }
}
```

Then error which I am getting is -

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[elasticsearch-backup] [[5_cX7DhMSw2KgPrVMEm3Gg, 'RemoteTransportException[[elastic-data-node-02][MY IP.11:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elasticsearch-backup] a file written by master to the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{elastic-data-node-02}{5_cX7DhMSw2KgPrVMEm3Gg}{KF6p34P9TSyp81QJQ56kgQ}{MY IP.11}{MY IP.11:9300}{di}{ml.machine_memory=8339873792, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]. This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [LhHj2udCRCWy7gt5iVQMsw, 'RemoteTransportException[[elastic-data-node-01][MY IP.10:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elasticsearch-backup] a file written by master to the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{elastic-data-node-01}{LhHj2udCRCWy7gt5iVQMsw}{S1TeQwE7Sjq6B__obrDEow}{MY IP.10}{MY IP.10:9300}{di}{ml.machine_memory=8339873792, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]. This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];']]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[elasticsearch-backup] [[5_cX7DhMSw2KgPrVMEm3Gg, 'RemoteTransportException[[elastic-data-node-02][MY IP.11:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elasticsearch-backup] a file written by master to the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{elastic-data-node-02}{5_cX7DhMSw2KgPrVMEm3Gg}{KF6p34P9TSyp81QJQ56kgQ}{MY IP.11}{MY IP.11:9300}{di}{ml.machine_memory=8339873792, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]. This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [LhHj2udCRCWy7gt5iVQMsw, 'RemoteTransportException[[elastic-data-node-01][MY IP.10:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elasticsearch-backup] a file written by master to the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{elastic-data-node-01}{LhHj2udCRCWy7gt5iVQMsw}{S1TeQwE7Sjq6B__obrDEow}{MY IP.10}{MY IP.10:9300}{di}{ml.machine_memory=8339873792, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]. This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];']]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: You might want to check this out: `This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node`. DO you have multiple nodes in your cluster? Do they share a filesystem?

Comment: yes i am using elasticsearch cluster

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions :-)

Comment: sorry i am using elasticsearch cluster with 1 master node and 2 data nodes............and as such i don t have any shared file system but i have made folder on same location in each node

Comment: Please Help!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This might indicate that the store [/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node

If you have multiple nodes and want to use the [**shared** file system repository (`fs`)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_shared_file_system_repository), you need to have a... **shared filesystem** that all nodes have access to, otherwise this cannot work.

In order to register the shared file system repository it is necessary to mount the same shared filesystem to the same location on all master and data nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @val said the file should be accessible for all nodes including the master and data nodes. I'm sharing a `docker-compose.yml` for you to test and understand better.

Please note that the snapshot mount directories(volumes) are accessible to all nodes.

```
opensearch-node1:
  environment:
    - path.repo=/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
  volumes:
    - opensearch-snapshot-data:/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
opensearch-node2:
  environment:
    - path.repo=/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
  volumes:
    - opensearch-snapshot-data:/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
volumes:
  opensearch-snapshot-data:
```

---

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.2.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1
      - path.repo=/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
      - opensearch-snapshot-data:/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.2.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - path.repo=/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
      - opensearch-snapshot-data:/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.2.1
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:
  opensearch-snapshot-data:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

---

#create a repository

```
PUT _snapshot/my-fs-repository
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/usr/share/opensearch/snapshots"
  }
}
```

#Verify the repository

```
POST _snapshot/my-fs-repository/_verify
```

#The following API will create a snapshot includes all indices and the cluster state

```
PUT _snapshot/my-fs-repository/1
```

#check the snapshot status, indices, etc.

```
GET _snapshot/my-fs-repository/1
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-filesystem-repository.html